# multiple matrices plotting in gnuplot

Tags: matrix, gnuplot

I have to plot multiple matrices using same set of colour scheme. Currently i'm using this programme.

```
do for [i=0:10] {
  set term png
  set output 'sort'.i.'.png'
  unset key                               
  plot 'sort'.i.'.dat' matrix with image
}
```

this is plotting different plots with different colour scheme.

Comment: So what is your actual question?

Comment: whenever I plot new image it starts with new colour range but I want to plot everything with same set of colour range so that I can make an animation.
Let me elaborate my question,
sort i .dat are 10 files with data at different time. now if I plot heatmaps of all the files and make a gif file then I can show the animation. But I am facing a problem:
Each file's heatmap has colour scale different i.e., if in first image 0 was white in next image it turns into red or blue because range of matrix elements changing in every data file.

Comment: Ok, now we're coming closer. Please update the question to include all that information.

Answer (score 0):

You must set a fixed `cbrange` for all plots. If you know this range in advance, you can simply set it with

```
set cbrange[min:max]
```

before starting to loop over the files.

If you don't know the range, then you must calculate it using the `stats` command before doing the plots:

```
max = min = 0
do for [i=0:10] {
  stats 'sort'.i.'.dat' matrix using 3 nooutput
  if (i == 0) {
    max = STATS_max
    min = STATS_min
  } else {
    if (STATS_max > max) { max = STATS_max }
    if (STATS_min < min) { min = STATS_min }
  }
}

set cbrange [min:max]

do for [i=0:10] {
  set term png
  set output 'sort'.i.'.png'
  unset key                               
  plot 'sort'.i.'.dat' matrix with image
}
```